# Efficient way to serve both API and web requests

Tags: laravel

With the following code, I can serve raw data to an API (or AJAX) client that passes the 'Accept' 'application/json' header, and a view with the data for web clients:

```
    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        return $laptops;
    } else {
        return view('laptops')->withLaptops($laptops);
    }
```

My question is, what's the best way to apply this logic to *every* request without copying the code into every Controller?

Comment: add a method to your base controller with parameters for viewName and data. put your if statement there. then just call that method when returning.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give you the best answer because you do not provide much details about your context.  Here is one possibility:

You could use two set of controllers

```
App\Http\Controllers
App\Http\Controllers\API
```

and use [resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers), to which you can also implement API versionning

```
Route::resource('laptop', 'LaptopController');
Route::resource('api/v1/laptop', 'API\LaptopController');
```

Finally, you abstract your controller logic to a service class such as

```
class LaptopService {

    protected $laptop;

    public function __construct($LaptopId){ 
          $this->laptop = Laptops::findOrFail($LaptopId);
    }

    public function get() {
       return $this->laptop;
    }
}
```

Then in your controllers you could have

```
public function show($id){
    $ls = new LaptopService($id)

    //In App\Http\Controllers
    //return view('laptops')->withLaptops($ls->get());
    //In  App\Http\Controllers\API
    //return Response::json($ls->get(), 200); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using the concept of `namespaces` and `routing groups`.
You can create 2 controllers of same name but with different namespaces.

Such as in your `routes.php`

```
// Routes pointing to the Controllers Within The "App\Http\Controllers" Namespace
Route::resource('laptops', 'LaptopsController');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', namespace' => 'Api'], function()
{
    // Routes pointing to Controllers Within The "App\Http\Controllers\Api" Namespace
    Route::resource('v1/laptops', 'LaptopsController');
});
```

> Your Controllers should be in the namespaces
>
> - App\Http\Controllers - `LaptopsComputer.php`
> - App\Http\Controllers\Api - `LaptopsComputer.php`

Your controller should include namespaces like:

```
// -------- App\Http\Controllers\LaptopsComputer.php --------
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class LaptopsComputer exends Controller {
    // Methods with reponse to WEB calls...
}

// -------- App\Http\Controllers\Api\LaptopsComputer.php --------
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
class LaptopsComputer exends Controller {
    // Methods with reponse to API calls...
}
```

For more reference about routings, take a look at - [Laravel Routing Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups)

Hope this helps you to make a proper use of one of the best features of Laravel.